# -subscribeNext: works, but RAC() doesn't

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

This works as expected:

```
        // Return a sequence for photos
    [[[[[[RACObserve(self, event.photos) filter:^BOOL(id value) { return value != nil ; }] flattenMap:^RACStream *(NSDictionary *photos)
        {
        NSLog(@"Got photos: %@" , photos) ;
        return photos.rac_sequence.signal ;
        }]

    // Consider each photo
    filter:^BOOL(NSDictionary *photoDescriptor)
        {
        NSLog(@"Descriptor: %@" , photoDescriptor) ;
        return ((NSNumber *)photoDescriptor[@"primary"]).boolValue ;
        }]

    // Load the selected photo
    map:^id(NSDictionary *selectedPhotoDescriptor)
        {
        NSLog(@"Photo URL: %@" , selectedPhotoDescriptor[@"url"]) ;
        return [[AsyncImageFetcher imageAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:selectedPhotoDescriptor[@"url"]] cache:YES] firstOrDefault:[UIImage imageNamed:@"detail_placeholder"]] ;
        }]

    // Deliver on main thread
    deliverOn:RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler]

    subscribeNext:^(id x)
        {
        ((UIImageView *)self.headerView).image = x ;
        }] ;
```

This does not; the image is never set:

```
    RAC( ((UIImageView *)self.headerView), image ) =

    // Return a sequence for photos
    [[[[[RACObserve(self, event.photos) filter:^BOOL(id value) { return value != nil ; }] flattenMap:^RACStream *(NSDictionary *photos)
        {
        NSLog(@"Got photos: %@" , photos) ;
        return photos.rac_sequence.signal ;
        }]

    // Consider each photo
    filter:^BOOL(NSDictionary *photoDescriptor)
        {
        NSLog(@"Descriptor: %@" , photoDescriptor) ;
        return ((NSNumber *)photoDescriptor[@"primary"]).boolValue ;
        }]

    // Load the selected photo
    map:^id(NSDictionary *selectedPhotoDescriptor)
        {
        NSLog(@"Photo URL: %@" , selectedPhotoDescriptor[@"url"]) ;
        return [[AsyncImageFetcher imageAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:selectedPhotoDescriptor[@"url"]] cache:YES] firstOrDefault:[UIImage imageNamed:@"detail_placeholder"]] ;
        }]

    // Deliver on main thread
    deliverOn:RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler] ;
```

Why?

Comment: Just a note, it's likely one of the problems is that -firstOrDefault: doesn't return a signal. I took that part out, but it's still not binding. I'll post an answer if I stumble across the answer.

Comment: Another problem, I'm returning a signal as a value in -map:. Looks like I'm getting my signals and values conflated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the version that works:

```
    // When there's a new image, fetch it, and set the headerView (which by default is an UIImageView)
RAC( self, imageView.image ) =

    // Return a sequence for photos
    [[[[RACObserve(self, event.photos) ignore:nil] flattenMap:^RACStream *(NSDictionary *photos)
        {
        NSLog(@"Got photos: %@" , photos) ;
        return photos.rac_sequence.signal ;
        }]

    // Consider each photo
    filter:^BOOL(NSDictionary *photoDescriptor)
        {
        NSLog(@"Descriptor: %@" , photoDescriptor) ;
        return ((NSNumber *)photoDescriptor[@"primary"]).boolValue ;
        }]

    // Load the selected photo
    flattenMap:^RACStream *(NSDictionary *selectedPhotoDescriptor)
        {
        NSLog(@"selected photo desc: %@" , selectedPhotoDescriptor) ;
        return [AsyncImageFetcher imageAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:selectedPhotoDescriptor[@"url"]] cache:YES] ; // This will -deliverOn: the main thread
        }] ;
```

Note that `AsyncImageFetcher`'s `imageAtURL:cache:` returns a signal.

A few notes about this solution:

First I had to create a new private property `self.imageView` that does nothing but return `self.headerView`. The reason for this relates to the arguments that the `RAC()` macro can accept. I became suspicious that the parameters I was passing to `RAC()` was causing my problem, so I simplified it by doing the cast in the aforementioned private property:

```
@synthesize imageView ;
- (UIImageView *) imageView
{
return (id) self.headerView ;
}
```

Then I tried:

```
RAC( self.imageView, image ) = …
```

But this didn't work. I then tried

```
RAC( self, imageView.image ) = …
```

This worked! So then I thought, let's get rid of `self.imageView` and see if it works with the casting right in the macro:

```
RAC( self, (((UIImageView *)headerView).image) ) = …
```

Unfortunately, this yields a syntax error.

So, the solution that utilizes the casting private property works, but it feels like a workaround. I'm accepting the answer since it works for me, but I'd still like to know if there's a way I can do this without creating the (redundant) imageView property.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar problems, and here are some of my thoughts.

1. `RAC(self.imageView, image)` binds the `image` key path on `self.imageView`, while `RAC(self, imageView.image)` binds the `imageView.image` key path on `self`. This basically means that the signal will only bind to the property `image` of `self.imageView` in the first case, but `imageView.image` of `self` in the second case. The difference is negligible in most scenario but according to what you have described the difference is likely crucial. If the binding happens before the creation of `imageView` only `RAC(self, imageView.image)` will work since `self.imageView` does not exist yet. (this most likely happens when imageView is an IBOutlet and the binding happens before viewDidLoad).
2. The reason `subscribeNext:` works is probably because when the Async signal sends next (which takes time), `imageView` is already created and so you can successfully assign image to it.